# How to map dynamic form data to Thymeleaf template?

Tags: html, spring-boot, thymeleaf, dynamicform

I need to convert a dynamic `HTML` to `Thymeleaf` template with `Spring boot`.

Below is the javascript to add two fields dynamically.

How can I map them in Thymeleaf?

```
function add() {
        var element = document.createElement("input");
        var foo = document.getElementById("fooBar");
        foo.appendChild(element);
}
<input type="button" value="Add" onclick="add()"/>
```

I have a `PoJo` to map the input data. How can I make the `Thymeleaf` template to map this data to `PoJo`.

Ex: Assume a Form with Student name and age field. I want to add more students data. Like: S1 20 S2 21 S3 25

I need to post this data using Thymeleaf, How can this be done? There is Student class on the server.

Comment: The question I'ts not clear for me, could you add more info?

Comment: I have a HTML form to which I dynamically add more fields. 
Ex:
 Assume a Form with Student name and age field. I want to add more students data. Like:
S1  20
S2  21
S3  25

I need to post this data using Thymeleaf, How can this be done?

There is Student class on the server.

Comment: Your form post has nothing to do with Thymeleaf. Thymeleaf just renders the form. Whether you use thymeleaf or not, your browser understands only pure html and javascript. Add the new html content you want inside the `<form>` tag and when you post the form the new HTML content values will also be posted. Later you can read that data in your controller from the post request.